# TYPO3 - Adding tx-news category to eventnews list item

Tags: typo3, fluid, tx-news

I have a problem with inserting to `eventnews` list view data from `tx-news` extension - for example: category title. I have tried with this code but it didn't works:

```
<f:if condition="{newsItem.categories}">
    <f:for each="{categories}" as="category">
        <f:if condition="{category.shortcut}">
            <f:then>
                <f:link.page pageUid="{category.shortcut}">
                    {category.title}
                </f:link.page>
            </f:then>
            <f:else>
                <span>{category.title}</span>
            </f:else>
        </f:if>
    </f:for>
</f:if>
```

Any suggestions how to display this data?

The whole list view template looks like that:

```
<f:section name="listItem">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">
        <strong>
            <n:link newsItem="{n}" settings="{settings}">{n.title}</n:link>
            | {f:format.date(date:n.datetime.date,format:'%d.%m')}</strong>
        <ul>
            <f:if condition="{n.organizer}">
                <li><strong>
                    <f:translate key="organizer" extensionName="eventnews" />
                </strong>: {n.organizer.title}
                    <small>(uid: {n.organizer.uid})</small>
                </li>
            </f:if>
            <f:if condition="{n.location}">
                <li><strong>
                    <f:translate key="location" extensionName="eventnews" />
                </strong>: {n.location.title}
                    <small>(uid: {n.location.uid})</small>
                </li>
            </f:if>
            <f:if condition="{n.eventEnd}">
                <li>
                    <strong>
                        <f:translate key="event_end" extensionName="eventnews" />
                    </strong>: {f:format.date(date:n.eventEnd.date,format:'%d.%m.%Y')}
                </li>
            </f:if>
        </ul>
    </div>
</f:section>
```

Comment: in your first code-snippet you do the condition on `newsitem.categories` but then you try to output `category.title`. how do you come from the first to the second? do you miss a `<f:for each="{newsitem.categories}" as "category">` ? (maybe with iterator usage. You should use ´<f:debug>` to inspect your available data.

Comment: You're right - I omitted part of the code. My fault. I edited the code and inserted the default category code from the tx-news plugin (on which I have worked), but still I can't generate category on output.

Comment: there still is the difference from `{newsItem.categories}`(1st line) to `{categories}` (2nd line 'each' parameter). I also miss the call/usage of the first snippet in the second snippet. Either as call to a partial/section (watch for arguments) or as copy.

Comment: Ok - I found a solution: `<f:for each="{n.categories}" as="category">{category.title}</f:for>

Comment: that's as I would expect it. I also expected you already did it.